# Под мышкой. Раздельное написание.

Tags: наречия, существительные

Можно ли считать корректным примером (взято у М. Булгакова) раздельного написания этой словоформы: «Пиджак, порван­ный под левой мыш­кой, был усе­ян соло­мой»?

Comment: А что Вас смущает в этом предложении?

Comment: В правилах не обговариваются и не даются такие примеры (с определениями для мышек).

Answer (score 4):

Нужно считать корректным. Словарь Кузнецова говорит:

> **ПОДМЫШКА**, -и; мн. род. -шек, дат. -шкам; ж. 1. (**в косвенных падежах
>   пишется раздельно**: под мышкой, под мышки и т.п.). Внутренняя часть
>   плечевого сгиба.

Comment: Ссылка на источник украсила бы этот ответ.

Comment: При имеющейся левой, в общем случае, есть и правая. Корректно ли будет говорить о расстоянии (в см) между мышками?

Comment: @shampar Вы можете измерить расстояние между подмышками, если установите края измерительной рулетки под мышками. А как бы Вы предложили написать это предложение?

Comment: Не ждал совета, но спасибо. Я логичный в развитие Вашего ответа вопрос задал.

Answer (score 3):

Подобный пример есть в словаре:

> [**Большой толковый словарь**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0&all=x)
>
> <...>
>
> 2. **МЫШКА**, -и; *мн. род.* -шек, *дат.* -шкам; ж. Мышца под плечевым сгибом. ***Болит под левой мышкой.*** Вода доходила до мышек. Держать
>      под мышками или под мышкой (под внутренней частью плечевого сгиба).
>      *Взять под мышки или под мышку* (под внутреннюю часть плечевого сгиба).

И говорил так не только Булгаков.

См. примеры:

*Он тащил **под левой мышкой** три книги и **под правой мышкой** три книги.*  [Солженицын. Раковый корпус (1968)]

***Под левой мышкой*** убитого синел Знак Огня, вывернутый лепестками вовнутрь. [Мария Семенова. Волкодав (2013)]

*Цыган хехекнул, почесал **под левой мышкой** и пошел прочь.* [Виктор Бурцев. Пленных не брать (2017)]

Answer (score 2):

Глядя на результаты поиска в Нацкорпусе, я пришел в недоумение. Такое впечатление, что правила мало кого ограничивают. Роман **под мышкой**, но книга **подмышкой**. Полуштоф **под левой мышкой**, а рука **под левой подмышкой**:

> Загорелый до черноты, в трусиках, с палкой, с детективным романом **под мышкой**, он отправлялся каждый день лежать голым в дюны. [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)]
>
> Михаил Веллер: Свою мечту я понял давно: по улицам идут толпы людей и у каждого **подмышкой** моя книга. [Юмор и скандал. Михаил Веллер о собственной прозе // РИА Новости, 2006.11.08]
>
> Немедленно вслед за этой вежливостью в примерочную прошел некто маловыразительный, правая рука **под левой подмышкой**. [Василий Аксенов. Новый сладостный стиль (2005)]
>
> Под левой мышкой он, горемычно улыбаясь, придерживал полуштоф. [А. И. Левитов. Беспечальный народ (1869)]

Если кто-то сможет все это уложить в какую-то схему — слава ему, а мне остается только высказать свое субъективное мнение. На мой взгляд, мышка — это мышца, а подмышка — это (1) поверхность тела под этой мышцей, (2) пустое пространство под ней, (3) наречие: (где) подмышкой, которое должно быть предпочтительней, чем (под чем) под мышкой. И никак не может быть "под ...подмышкой", а если нет выхода, то писать: "Под левой/правой мышкой", но лучше бы так: "Подмышкой слева/справа".

Answer (score 1):

***Под левой мышкой, под правой мышкой*** ― эти выражения присутствуют в словаре, но в современном языке используются редко, поэтому они необычны для слуха. Все приведенные в Нацкорпусе примеры относятся **к старым текстам**:

**Под правой мышкой** немного жало, но от этого еще лучше прихватывало на талии. [Н. В. Гоголь. Мертвые души (1842)]

**Под левой мышкой** он, горемычно улыбаясь, придерживал полуштоф. [А. И. Левитов. Беспечальный народ (1869)]

Современный текст:

― Дела, ― сказал Петр Сергеевич, **зажал под мышкой** потёртую кожаную папку, с которой Андрей не видел его уже года три, и выскочил в коридор. [Виктор Пелевин. Желтая стрела (1993)]

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EF%EE%E4+%EB%E5%E2%EE%E9+%EC%FB%F8%EA%EE%E9

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EF%EE%E4+%EF%F0%E0%E2%EE%E9+%EC%FB%F8%EA%EE%E9

Comment: А как принято выражаться сейчас? Слева подмышкой?

Comment: Никак не принято. Данная деталь несущественна. Но если обе руки заняты, то можно сказать так: В левой рук он держал портфель, а справа под мышкой зажал кожаную папку.

Comment: А как Вам такое: Под левой подмышкой―якорь! 5. [Дмитрий СМИРНОВ, Фото: РЕЙТЕР, globallookpress.com, FOTOBANK, Михаил ФРОЛОВ, Splash, All Over Press.. Леди Гага: «Я пишу песни под платья» // Комсомольская правда, 2013.04.17]

Comment: И вообще, можно ли писать слитно *подмышкой*? В Нацкорлусе 169 вхождений против 1580 с раздельным написанием.

Comment: Нормально, классики используют это выражение: Немедленно вслед за этой вежливостью в примерочную прошел некто маловыразительный, правая рука под левой подмышкой. [Василий Аксенов. Новый сладостный стиль (2005)]  Но "под левой мышкой" явно устарело.

Comment: И вообще, можно ли писать слитно подмышкой? — Когда это слово относят к суще­стви­тель­ным пер­во­го скло­не­ния.

Comment: Вообще говоря, подмышка/мышка - это мышца. Из-за этого можно встретить разные написания с предлогом ПОД: зажать  под мышкой (где), зажать подмышкой (чем).

Comment: А это как: Подмышкой (где) у него была чья-то скрипка, которую он куда-то нёс продавать. [Ф. М. Достоевский. Господин Прохарчин (1846)]

Comment: Не надо подходить к решению задачи формально, выбирайте его по смыслу для каждого случая. Под мышкой (где) у него была чья-то скрипка.  Замените в вашем примере слово "подмышка" словом "мышца" и посмотрите, что у вас получится.

Comment: Люди сейчас говорят так: *под левой подмышкой* (и никаких левых мышек).