# Употребление слова "подмышка"

Tags: орфография

Читая книгу Бориса Акунина "Азазель", я наткнулся на следующее предложение:

> По коридорам деловито рысили какие-то незнакомые господа с папками подмышкой, и даже прежние сослуживцы ходили уже не вперевалочку, а резво, подтянуто.

Если я правильно понимаю, то слово подмышка в данном случае должно писаться раздельно:
"Он держал градусник под мышкой", "Они несли папки под мышкой".

Почему у Акунина оно написано слитно и имеет ли здесь место простая опечатка?

Comment: Замечательные рассуждения и примеры есть здесь: **Под мышкой. Раздельное написание.** https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/444088/Под-мышкой-Раздельное-написание/444095#444095